# ncurses write to window not displayed

Tags: c, panel, ncurses

I've got one function do_refresh which should draw some character in a window like this:

```
void do_refresh(WINDOW *w_game, int *xPos, int *yPos, char vector[], snake *snake){
    mvwaddch(w_game, (*yPos), (*xPos), snake->headsym);// mv to new pos and place char
    wrefresh(w_game);
}
```

The window w_game has also a panel pendant which lies on top of all other panels.
Before that function gets called, I let the user do non blocking input with getch() and timeout(0):

```
fflush(stdin);
key = getch();
if(key != ERR){ ...
```

only the first time I call do_refresh, the char gets drawn to the window, later nothing changes though xPos & yPos as well as all other parameters to mvwaddch are valid and change over the time.

Doing a redrawwin on the window causes a segfault, using wgetch(w_game) instead of getch() returns no input.

I would be *very* grateful if someone could at least link to a decent documentation what has to be considered when using wgetch instead and what it does different.

**UPDATE**
I found the solution to the problem, The function which sets up the panel stuff modifies **the address** of the windows!, you have to return the (new) destination of the pointer to main and reset it there like this:

```
...setup_panels(...){
  return w_game; // my window
}
int main(...){
  WINDOW *w_game;
  [...]
  w_game = setup_panels(...);
}
```

Comment: In terms of ncurses documentation I find that nothing beats the man pages. http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html

Comment: I read nothing about the change of the pointer in the doc but thanks anyway.

Comment: Can you please move the Update text to an answer (below) and mark it as an answer?

Comment: there's no such button to answer my own q